# Converting Esri Grid format (adf files) to GeoTIFF using Python and ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, raster-conversion, esri-grid-format

In ArcGIS Pro, I am attempting to convert and export Esri Grid Format (ADF) files that are rasters to TIFF files. I want to be able to do this in Python using ArcPy. However, when I attempt to use the tool 'Raster to Other Format', I received errors for each raster conversion.

Below is my code:

```
arcpy.conversion.RasterToOtherFormat(r"path to 1st raster';'path to 2nd raster';'path to 3rd raster';'path to 4th raster'", r"path to 5th raster", "TIFF")
```

Below is the error I get on each raster:

> Failed to convert: . ERROR 160180: The junction has invalid geometry (i.e., non-point or invalid location).
> Failed to execute (CopyRaster).

Is there a way I can create code that export ESRI grid formatted rasters to a different raster type? I do no necessarily have to use ArcPy to accomplish this. It seems as if there is very little information out there discussing coverages and how to manipulate/export them.

Comment: Try exporting one at at time. If your sample code had actual names, the problem would be more obvious.

Comment: @Vince can each single .adf file being exported at a time? Each ESRI Grid raster that I listed above in my question, is in a folder containing the following files for each: ```dblbnd.adf, hdr.adf, prj.adf, sta.adf, w001001.adf, w001001x.adf```

Comment: As @Hornbydd answered, those are not rasters.  All those files together are a *single* grid, when referenced by the parent folder name (if it has a conforming directory name -- no leading numeric, no dot or dash)

Answer (score 1):

If you type ADF into the ArcGIS Pro help file, what do you get? Absolutely nothing, that's because ADF is not a raster file format. You almost certainly have an ESRI GRID raster which is a FOLDER with files, some being ADF. You need to export the folder not its contents.  You might benefit from reading this page on [raster formats](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm)?

Comment: I do have a ESRI GRID raster in a folder with files, all of them being ADF files. The files are in formats and named like so: ```dblbnd.adf, hdr.adf, prj.adf, sta.adf, w001001.adf, w001001x.adf```

Comment: So it's the folder that holds those file that is the "raster".

Comment: understood. So the actual folder name is what needs to be exported?